# Ticket system - show message when a user does not have any tickets

Tags: php, ticket-system

I am working on a new ticket system, but something went wrong. When a user does not have an open ticket, it should show this message:

```
 <?}else{?>
<tr>
     <td style="background:#f7f7f7;">There are no tickets submitted yet.</td>
     </tr>
<?}?>
```

I probably did something wrong and I cannot figure out where. This is the code that I have:

```
<?php 
if($_GET['a'] == "del" && $_GET['id'] != ""){
mysql_query("DELETE FROM message WHERE id='{$_GET['id']}' LIMIT 1;");
}

$msg = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `message` WHERE `receiver`='{$_SESSION['login']}' ORDER BY date DESC")or die (mysql_error());
?>
<table id="nested" width="97%" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr><th width="50px">ID</th><th width="110px">Date</th><th width="165px">Title</th><th width="90px">Status</th><th align="right" width="60px">Actions</th></tr></div>
<tbody>
<?php 
while($mesg = mysql_fetch_array($msg)) {
?>
<tr class="">
<th><?php echo $mesg['id']; ?> </th>
<td><?php echo $mesg['date']; ?> </td>
<td><?php echo $mesg['title']; ?> </td>

<td><?php
if($mesg['readed']) { echo "Read";
}else{ echo "Unread";
} ?> </td>
<th><ul class="action-buttons">


<li><a href="#myTickets?id=<?=$mesg['id']?>" class="action-button" title="Read"><span class="read"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#myTickets?a=del&id=<?=$mesg['id']?>" class="action-button" title="Delete"><span class="delete"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#myTickets?a=close&id=<?=$mesg['id']?>" class="action-button" title="Close"><span class="close"></span></a></li></ul>

<? } ?>

 </th>

<?}else{?>
    <tr>
         <td style="background:#f7f7f7;">There are no tickets submitted yet.</td>
         </tr>
    <?}?>

</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</table>
```

Please if anyone can help me, I would appreciate it very much, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `if` statement to match the `else`.  Either add an `if` for when there are tickets, or just change the `else` into an `if` that evaluates to `true` when there *aren't* tickets.

For example:

```
<?if ( mysql_num_rows($msg) == 0 ) {?>
    <tr>
        <td style="background:#f7f7f7;">There are no tickets submitted yet.</td>
    </tr>
<?}?>
```

Comment: Hopefully this will point you in the right direction.  But you need to read the php docs on the `if` statement.  ["The `if` construct is one of the most important features of many languages, PHP included."](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)

Comment: You're welcome. Please ["Accept"](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) this answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your braces. Its not balanced.

```
<?php 
     if( mysql_num_rows($msg) == 0 ) { ?>    //means the query returns empty set.
        <tr>
             <td style="background:#f7f7f7;"> //There are no tickets submitted yet.</td>
        </tr>
<?php } else {  // you have messages
    while($mesg = mysql_fetch_array($msg)) {
         // finish ur while loop
 ?>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new in php, I do not understand what you mean with this... you can do eg where to change?